# Как создать миграцию старой базы в новую (ларавел)?

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Делаю миграцию старой базы на новую, сайт на ларавел. Идея примерно следующая: старая база развернута, в файле .env создано к ней подключение. Создан сидер, в котором собственно и происходит миграция. Но осталась одна трудность, которую пока не победили. В старой базе есть поле salary. Там есть все что хочешь: 5000, >1000, <5000, от 1000, 1000 - 3000. Примерно такое там записано. А в новой базе разделено на salary_from i salary_to. И эти старые данные надо как правильно разделить и перенести. Если одно число, тогда по идеи это salary_to, если что то типо 1000 -3000, тогда salary_from = 1000, salary_to = 3000. Как это сделать? Есть мнение что надо писать регулярные выражения, но что то не получаеться...

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать оператор CONTAINS и подзапросы. Но остается открытым вопрос: что за база и объем данных.
Подробнее об операторе [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)